# Find a specific tag with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, url, findelement

[image]

I want to be able to get id_documento with selenium.
this tag is recurring  in the table

[image]

Afer this step I want to print out a Url that has the variable document in it

I wrote this to get the tag:

```
Documents = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/table/tbody[4]')
Document = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'id_documento')
```

and this for the url

```
Url = 'https://download' + document + 'default'
```

but i get errors beacause it's not a string

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `.text` at the end of document command, like this:

```
Document = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'id_documento').text
```

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work